# how I check my installed svchost files if any is a virus or keylogger?

Tags: virus, svchost, keylogger

HI,
I have kaspersky but like all anti virus it may miss a file and I have 14 services of svchost listed on my task manager, how to check if any of them is a virus or keylogger ?

thanks

Comment: Which version of Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not unusual to have more than a dozen svchost running at once. If every service ran from the same instance of svchost and one crashed it would bring the rest with it. If you're curious, run the following from a command prompt:

tasklist /SVC

Answer (score 1):

You don't know if they're viruses, but if Kaspersky says everything's fine, you're probably worried about nothing.

Use Process Explorer from [SysInternals](http://www.sysinternals.com), and hover your mouse over each instance of `svchost` to see which services they are running, just to be on the safe side.

Answer (score 0):

A good malware scanner ([MBAM](http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html), or [SAS](http://download.cnet.com/SuperAntiSpyware-Free-Edition/3000-8022_4-10523889.html)) will scan memory space and running processes to find any nefarious program running inside of svchost.